# How to add strings "<fc=ff00>" before any line containing the pattern [:alpha:], but not add two consecutive lines?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Consider this sample file:

```
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters.
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters,
```

I'd like add strings  just a single line of text.

```
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00 >Alphabetic characters,
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters,
```

using sed: 
    sed '/[[:alpha:]]/s/^//' file >new_file

I'm not clear how to exclude second line. Any suggestion?

Comment: the `^M`s are actually `\r` right? and this is a `.srt` file right? I don't see what the <br/> tags are doing here. is this converted to html?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The `<br/>` tags are leftovers from converting to a code block and shouldn't be there, I think.

Comment: maybe you could [edit] them out, alongside the ^M ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you're right, is .srt file!  The correction has been made Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!f && /[[:alpha:]]/{print "<fc=ff00>" $0; f=1; next} {print; f=0}' file
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters.
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters,
```

Comment: Thanks for a awk answer @Ed Morton, but the output of this command does not add the strings for me, Also I tried, this  "/[:alpha:]/" but I did not succeed.   Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Of course it does, just look at my answer to see it being executed and the output it produces. Yes you did something wrong - `[:alpha:]` is a character class, you need to put it inside a bracket expression `[...]` to use it in a regexp comparison, `/[[:alpha:]]/`.

Comment: I edited my question and post the output of the suggested command.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You must be using an old, non-POSIX awk that doesn't recognize POSIX character classes, maybe nawk or mawk. The closest approximation for one of those would be `/[a-zA-Z]/`. And stop trying to use `/[:alpha:]/` - that means "any of the characters `: a l p h`" which is not what you want. See my previous comment.