# How to add strings “< /font>” after lines beginning with < fc=ff00>, but not add two consecutive lines?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Consider this sample file:

```
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters.
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters,
```

I'd like add strings just a single line of text.

```
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters.</font>
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,</font>
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters,</font>
```

I'm not clear how to exclude first line. Any suggestion?

Comment: haven't you asked this question a few days ago?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40728658/3776858 I believe the question was the precursor to this question here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A little different, I need help to add suffix not prefix.

Comment: Don't you really want to do both things at the same time?

Comment: @EdMorton If possible, Would be great !!

Comment: Why go into the trouble of describing the format to the last bit when you want to **add font** (or something similar) **to subtitles**?? It's called [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) and people [don't tend to like it around here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: E.g. next question could easily be "how to add `<fc=ff00>...</font>` to lines which only contain numbers and punctuation, but don't contain a `-->`, or contain that, but not a colon, or [10^6 other special cases]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think you're really trying to do:

```
$ cat file
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters.
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
Alphabetic characters,

$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:alpha:]]/ { buf = (buf ? buf RS : "") $0; next }
buf { printf "<fc=ff00>%s</font>\n", buf; buf="" }
{ print }
END { if (buf) printf "<fc=ff00>%s</font>\n", buf }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
01
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters.</font>
02
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters
Alphabetic characters,</font>
03
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
<fc=ff00>Alphabetic characters,</font>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^<fc=ff00>[a-zA-Z ,.]\+/! p;' \
       -e '/^<fc=ff00>[a-zA-Z ,.]\+/ { :start $! N; /\n[a-zA-Z ,.]\+$/  b start;  s/\(.*\)\n/\1<\/font>\n/p; $ s/\(.*\)/\1<\/font>/p}' \
       file
```

If you want to have an explenation, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 'N;/[[:alpha:]].*\n[^[:alpha:]]*$/s/\n/<\/font>&/;$s/$/<\/font>/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines at a time and if the first contains an alphabetic character and the second does not, insert the required string before the newline.Always do the above substitution on the last line of the file. Then print and delete the first of the two lines and append another in the next cycle and so on.